# How to script click to cframe or vector

Tags: lua, exploit

How can the script automatically click on the CFrame or vector of a part?

I tried virtual user but i dont know Am I doing it wrong or the script is not working but it doesn't work
I also tried searching on all social media platforms but I couldn't find it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.